# Ethereum selection of peer nodes and centralization

Tags: peers, decentralization, bitshares

How does Ethereum select peer nodes when it starts ?
I guess there should be a set of nodes hardcoded in geth that it tries to connect to and then gets list of other nodes from them.
How many of those nodes is hardcoded into geth ?
Are they hardcoded by IP address or domain name ?
How would Ethereum network survive if all these nodes are shut down by joint governments ban.

Comparing Ethereum decentralization to Bitshares 101 nodes centralization, if there are less than 101 hardcoded initial peers in Ethereum, then it seems like it is not more decentralized than Bitshares, but far slower. Is my understanding correct ?

If not done already, are there any plans to publish list of active nodes on the blockchain so that next time geth starts it can try to connect to latest list rather than hardcoded list.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/what-are-the-peer-discovery-mechanisms-involved-in-ethereum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does Ethereum select peer nodes when it starts ? I guess there
>   should be a set of nodes hardcoded in geth that it tries to connect to
>   and then gets list of other nodes from them. How many of those nodes
>   is hardcoded into geth ?

There are 3 hard-coded bootnodes. See [How many bootnodes are hardcoded into Ethereum clients?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/how-many-bootnodes-are-hardcoded-into-ethereum-clients)

> Are they hardcoded by IP address or domain name ?

They're hardcoded as enode URLs, such as: `"enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c@52.16.188.185:30303"`

> How would Ethereum network survive if all these nodes are shut down by
>   joint governments ban.

That's speculative. I'm assuming they'd create some more, and we'd enter an arms race of sorts.

> Comparing Ethereum decentralization to Bitshares 101 nodes
>   centralization, if there are less than 101 hardcoded initial peers in
>   Ethereum, then it seems like it is not more decentralized than
>   Bitshares, but far slower. Is my understanding correct ?

The 3 hard-coded nodes are bootstrap nodes, whose purpose is to allow entry to the peer-to-peer network (and I *think* this is only for the first time a node enters the network - subsequent connections can use other nodes, mentioned in the answer to your final question). They don't serve all the data.

Ethereum uses a Kademlia-like system to discover further peers. The maximum number of peers is also configurable.

See [How does Ethereum client select which peers to synchronise with?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/how-does-ethereum-client-select-which-peers-to-synchronise-with)

> If not done already, are there any plans to publish list of active
>   nodes on the blockchain so that next time geth starts it can try to
>   connect to latest list rather than hardcoded list.

This isn't quite handled the way you're suggesting at present, but there are more options than just connecting to the 3 hard-coded peers on each startup.

- "bootstrap" nodes: These are the 3 hard-coded nodes.
- ["static"](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes) nodes: These can be explicitly added by the user.
- ["trusted"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-node-and-a-trusted-node) nodes: These can also be configured, and are always connected to, even if the maximum (soft limit) number of peers has been reached.

Publishing a huge list, rather than letting the discovery protocol do its work, would possibly provide an attack surface for people wanting to publish their own, corrupt list.